# Websocket only sends onopen (Javascript in HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

Websocket only sends a message if onopen was invoked and no where else. The server just sends back the message with Hello added.

Client side:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="transmit()">send</button>
        <h3 id="text"></h3>
    </body>
    <script>
            const url = "ws://localhost:8765"
            const ws = new WebSocket(url)
            var i = 0;

            ws.onopen = function (event) {
                ws.send('On');
            }

            ws.onmessage = function (event){
                ws.send("This will cause a feedback loop but idc at this point");
                var text = document.getElementById("text");
                text.innerHTML = evt.data;
            }

            ws.send("pain");
                
    </script>
</html>
```

I am probably doing something stupid lol.

Answer (score 1):

Websockets closes automatically upon no activity, afterwards all send is ignored. To prevent it from closing here is an approach.

```js
ws.onopen = function (event) {
  ws.send('On');

  return false; // keeps the socket open.
}

//or 
ws.onmessage = function (event){
   ws.send("This will cause a feedback loop but idc at this point");
   var text = document.getElementById("text");
   text.innerHTML = evt.data;

   return false; // keeps the socket open.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It still doesn't send after onopen tho.

Comment: you can return false on that too actually, just to keep it open. See edits.

Comment: It is still not working for some reason